# Google Drive Storing images - bad or good way

Tags: php, mysql, hibernate, ftp, google-drive-api

Using google drive for storing images(Instead of the usual way ftp, blobs..) for a  website with 10,000 users per day is it a good or bad way?

Considering API application requests per day and google free account with 15 GB space.

Comment: show us the pros and cons youve compiled so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seriously looking at serving images to anonymous users on a website, you should consider proper storage designed for this type of use case, such as [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) or [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Google Drive is designed for "your content" and sharing between people you know. Using it for a general website will likely trip up automatic abuse filters at scale and will not lead to a good time.

Comment: I have website wich users can upload files. every user can upload 20 picures per account, every picture take 43 kb. I thinkng, why pay money for storage if i can store the picures in google drive or dropbox and path them in mysql..

Comment: Because it isn't designed to be used in that manner, and as I mentioned, can result in things like abuse detection being triggered which would bring your site down. Serving 100K users via GCS would cost only $2/month in storage costs if they all did 20 x 43kb images. https://www.google.com/search?q=20+*+42kib+*+100000+*+%240.026%2Fgib

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Photos which has Free unlimited uploads if the photos are smaller than 16 MP and there also might be a size restriction. More informations [here](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?hl=en).

Also, there is an API for Google Photos through Picasa API. More informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533971/is-there-an-upload-api-for-google-photos-photos-google-com)