# Google Photos URI API

Tags: android, api, uri

I don't know if there is an API or an URI scheme for the Android and iOS version for the Google Photos app for the search engine.
I want to send a search query to the Google Photos app, which shows me all the pictures with that query. Do you know if there is something?

Thanks for any response.

Edit:
I don't want to upload the photos. I just want to query it via the search engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an upload API for Google Photos (photos.google.com)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533971/is-there-an-upload-api-for-google-photos-photos-google-com)

Comment: Picasa Web Albums Data API no longer supports community search: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/ So you might want to explain what kind of search you are looking for (filename, image).

Comment: When you open the Google Photos app on Android, there is on the top a search field, where you can search all your photos. Is there an URI scheme, where I can run an query via that field?

Comment: I would look to see if this: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference and this https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#q are still available and meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, which solves my problem.

Google Photos is also providing his photo service in the web. When you search in the search bar on the top, it will generate a link like this:

**https://photos.google.com/search/`<query>`**

Now replace the `<query>` with the search you want to request. The results are still the same like on android and iOS.

When you open that link on an android device, the Google Photos app will open automatically.

Here's a sample for a request:

https://photos.google.com/search/black%20cat

Comment: This seems to solve it on Android, but not on iOS. I haven't figured out a way to pass the same `search` keyword to URL scheme `googlephotos://`

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out.  have any luck?